# Cannot read from BigQuery

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I try to read a simple BigQuery table.

This hangs on:

```
WARNING:root:Dataset thijs-dev:temp_dataset_b234824381e04e1324234237724b485f95c does not exist so we will create it as temporary with location=EU
```

For this I use the following script:

```
python main.py \
  --runner DirectRunner \
  --project thijs-dev \
  --temp_location gs://thijs/tmp/ \
  --job_name thijs-dev-load \
  --save_main_session
```

And the complete Python script:

```
import apache_beam as beam

import logging
import argparse


def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)


    with beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args) as p:
        """ Read all data from source_table """
        source_data = (p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query="select * from `thijs-dev.metathijs.thijs_locations`", use_standard_sql=True)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Start")
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Comment: Do you know in which location your script is running?

Comment: the location is EU

Comment: Dont you get results in your query?

Comment: I see that you are using DirectRunner are you credentials setup properly ? Also, you can check Bigquery UI to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I found out Dataflow is just extremely slow. It takes 30 minutes to process 26MB of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Dataflow is just extremely slow. It takes half an hour to process 26MB of data but it is working afterall.

Comment: I would only like to clarify that when using the [DirectRunner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) (as set up in your Python command) the Apache Beam pipeline you deploy runs locally. To make use of the Dataflow service to run your pipeline on GCP infrastructure use the [DataflowRunner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/) instead.